# How can I verify mysql cell content before doing next process in Tkinter

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter

I am new to TKINTER/PYTHON

Below is a example syntax. I want to basically keep checking MYSQL cell to see if status changes from down to anything else and report the change to the shell listbox.

I want to check every so often thus monitoring db activity and once the status has changed as per that cell, stop doing the after() process and complete the listbox update.

```
def machstat():
dbi = mdb.connect("localhost", port=3306, user="access", passwd="password", db="database")
cursor = dbi.cursor()

cursor.execute("""SELECT operation FROM status WHERE mach1='down' """)
stat = cursor.fetchone()
for stat  #THIS WHERE I NEED HELP

   if stat == 'down' then root.after(2000, machstat)
else  (AFTER PROCESS STOP)
   for results in stat:
        List.insert("end", results)
```

Comment: what is the problem ? do you get error message ? always put full error message (Traceback) in question (as text, not screenshot). There are other useful informations.

Comment: you have wrong indentions. Edit question and use button `{}` to format code.

Comment: you could connect and create cursor only once, and use `after` to run  `execute()`

Comment: to check if something changed in database you should keep previous values form database and compare with new values from database. Or you should keep in database when value was changed (new column with `update_time`) and then you can `SELECT` values using date/time of previous checking. So seems your problem is `database`, not `tkinter`

Comment: There are no errors, I want to get help with the if statement.  I want Python to do a database query as shown and continue checking 'after()' until the cell status changes, fetch the changed result and stop. The Mysql statement is correct, that is a sample or conceptual of the syntax.

Comment: I will move the sql connect out of the def - it is there for reference only

Comment: instead of concept create real code and test it. You can use `print(...)` and `print(type(...))` to see what you have in variables - ie. in `stat`. It should help you to create correct code.